# How to do multiple Dask computations without re-loading my large CSV

Tags: python, dask

I have to process a number of large (ca. 10GB) CSV files. I'm currently using Dask to pre-process the data into some aggregated statistics, which I then further analyze with regular Pandas.

The problem I'm having is that Dask reloads the data for every call to `compute()`. Some dummy code to illustrate the problem:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_csv('very_large_file.csv')  # ca. 10GB

# Every line seems to trigger painfully slow re-reading of the CSV file from disk!
groupstats_A = ddf.groupby(['col1', 'col2']) \
                  .mean() \
                  .compute()
groupstats_B = ddf.groupby(['col3']) \
                  .mean() \
                  .compute()
groupstats_C = ddf.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) \
                  .mean() \
                  .compute()
```

Is there a way to optimize this code in such a way that the `compute()` function does not have to read the large file from disk at every call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot like a duplicate, but I cannot find the original.

You can pass multiple things to compute as follows, and any possible intermediates will be shared.

```
groupstats_A = ddf.groupby(['col1', 'col2']) \
                  .mean()
groupstats_B = ddf.groupby(['col3']) \
                  .mean()
groupstats_C = ddf.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) \
                  .mean()
A, B, C = dask.compute(groupstats_A, groupstats_B, groupstats_C)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did look for duplicates as well, but couldn't find it either. This answer is exactly what I was looking for, it makes everything so much faster.